# The veiled guise of binary and string

Tags: beginner, c, programming-challenge, strings, steganography

#### Challenge

Conceal a binary code within a word.

#### Specifications

1. The first argument is a path to a file.
2. The file contains multiple lines.
3. Each line is a test case represented by a space separated word and a binary code.
4. For each test case, print the binary masked word.
5. The mask alters the word according to the following:

   - If the bit is 1, change the letter to upper case.
   - If the bit is 0, leave the letter as is.

#### Constraints

1. Words are from 1 to 20 letters long.
2. The length of each word is equal to the length of the binary code.
3. Words are always in lower case.
4. The number of test cases is 40.

**Sample Input**

> hello 11001
>   world 10000
>   cba 111

**Sample Output**

> HEllO
>   World
>   CBA

[Source](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/199/)

**My Solution**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LINE_BUFFER 42

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        puts("File path not provided.");
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc > 2) {
        puts("Excessive arguments, only the first will be considered.");
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(args[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        puts("Could not access file / file not found.");
        return 1;
    }

    char line[LINE_BUFFER];
    while (fgets(line, LINE_BUFFER, file)) {
        for (int i = 0, word_length = 0; ; i++, word_length++) {
            if (line[i] == ' ') {
                line[i++] = '\0';
                for (int j = 0; j < word_length; j++, i++) {
                    if (line[i] == '1') {
                        line[j] = toupper(line[j]);
                    }
                }
                printf("%s\n", line);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Handling arguments and errors

In C, `args` is conventionally called `argv`.

Do not contaminate `stdout` with error messages, which should go to `stderr` instead.  One way to write error messages to `stderr` is using `fprintf(stderr, …)`.  However, a more idiomatic and informative way is using `perror()`.  For example, `perror(args[1])` might print an error message like `blah.txt: No such file or directory`.

An even friendlier solution is to interpret the spec in such a way that there aren't so many possible error conditions.  For example, if there are no files specified you could just read from `stdin`, and if there are multiple files specified you could process them all.

### Code structure

I'm not a fan of the `while`–`for`–`if`–`for`–`if` nesting, especially since the body of `if (line[i] == ' ')` only runs once per line.  I think that the code would be tidier if you searched for the space delimiter using `strchr()`.  If you are on a system where `strsep()` is available (such as [BSD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strsep.3.html) or [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html)), use that instead.  Otherwise, [`strtok()`, `strtok_r()`, or `strtok_s()`](//stackoverflow.com/a/9021615/1157100) could also work.

You don't need `printf("%s", …)` when `puts(…)` will do.

### Suggested solution

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 42

int toggle_case(FILE *file) {
    char line[BUFFER_SIZE], *word, *mask;
    while (fgets(line, BUFFER_SIZE, file)) {
        if (!(mask = strchr(line, ' '))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input: %s\n", line);
            return -1;
        }

        for (*mask++ = '\0', word = line; *word && *mask; mask++, word++) {
            if (*mask == '1') {
                *word = toupper(*word);
            }
        }
        puts(line);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = stdin;
    if (argc <= 1) {
        toggle_case(stdin);
    } else for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (NULL == (file = fopen(argv[i], "r"))) {
            perror(argv[i]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        int err = toggle_case(file);
        fclose(file);
        if (err) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with everything you said – apart from putting `*mask++ = '\0'` into the for-loop :)

Answer (score 11):

- **`42`**

  ```
  #define LINE_BUFFER 42
  ```

  `42` is not a *buffer*. Besides being a meaning of life, the universe, and everything, it is *size*. Consider renaming it to `LINE_BUFFER_LENGTH`.
- **No naked loops**

  Every loop represents some algorithm, and therefore deservers a name. Consider

  ```
  while (fgets(line, LINE_BUFFER, file)) {
      char * mask = find_separator(line);
      *mask++ = '\0';
      convert_word_according_to_mask(line, mask);
      printf("%s\n", line);
  }
  ```
- **Errors** (like `fopen` returning NULL) are better handled with `perror()` or `strerror(errno)`. Both functions precisely describe what went wrong.

Comment: Hm. So like [this](https://ideone.com/AGKCPK)?

Comment: @Legato Looks right, but please sep _a_ rator